# How I change the button color after clicking on itself?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themeroller

I have created 3 themes on http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/. Each theme has a different button color. I tried to change the following button theme from data theme a to data theme c:

```
<button data-icon="star" data-theme="a" data-form="ui-btn-up-a" id="btnA" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-disabled="false">0,2 m3</button>
```

using this function:

```
$("#btnA").click(function()
{
    $("#btnA").buttonMarkup({theme: 'c'});
});
```

but the color of `btnA` doesn't change. How do I proceed?

Comment: it should work normally with refreshing. You have the correct code, what error are you getting?

Comment: Your code works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/RjkJU/

Answer (score 1):

Once you have set set the theme on the button you'll need to call `refresh` on it like below...

```
$("#btnA").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-theme","c").button('refresh');
});
```

Enjoy...